# How to increase sidekiq process execution time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, fb-graph

We have used `sidekiq` process to post advertisement to `facebook` with `fb_graph` .

Each time if there are bunch of processes to be executed at same time, they are causing the server crash .

Probably the time for posting to facebook is running longer via `page.feed!()` .

How to increase sidekiq process execution time?

Answer (score 0):

Lower the default concurrency of 25 to something like 5 or even lower, using `-c`.  Sounds like the code might not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq task stops its execution after completing itself. There is no limit of time for a particular task to complete its job. Assuming you are calling some facecook api for `page.feed!()` increasing the timeout of your http call should do the trick.